# How to filter cards based on table data row selection in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, filtering, data-visualization, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I am working on a report that deals in employee feedbacks. I have different cards on top to show -
(Requests Received,Type of requests(social/others/security),Requests reported/not reported and expired).

All these cards have data based on a measure - `Count of Employee IDs = count('vw_EmployeeFeedback'[Employee_Id]) + 0`  and respective filter fields dragged on to them to show category type etc.

Below them I have a table to show the detailed view of the data. Such as names of manager raising the request, Request raised for(name field) , status of requests, submitted date etc. coming from the same view as Count of Employee Ids.

[image: Card and Table design picture]

***I want the cards to filter based on the selection of a row in the table.***

The edit interaction are set to filter the cards, but all go zero or blank when I select a row in the table.

Please let me know how I can achieve this. Thank You!

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that you have different tables for your data source/s that is why it is not filtering when clicking the table entry. Try establishing the relationships of your tables. Just go to Models and then Manage Relationships. If it's not the case, then you need other solutions.

Comment: @RKKK, Can you please provide some more details about data model? Where does the data come from? Which tables are you using to create visuals? Do you have any relation between the tables? etc,etc...